# Conflict with different routes in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a website that manages inventory for restaurants. These are the routes I have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Inventory",                            
    "Inventory/{restaurantName}/{restaurantLocationId}/{code}",
    new { controller = "Inventory", action = "Index" },
    new[] { "MySite.Web.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(    // this route doesn't work
    "ListRestaurantInventory",
    "Inventory/List/{restaurantLocationId}/{code}",
    new { controller = "Inventory", action = "ListRestaurantInventoryItems" },
    new[] { "MySite.Web.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "InventoryDetails",
    "Inventory/{restaurantName}/{restaurantLocationId}/{code}/Details/{restaurantInventoryItemId}",
    new { controller = "Inventory", action = "Details" },
    new[] { "MySite.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

The problem is with the `ListRestaurantInventory` route, I get a 404 if I try to navigate to `/Inventory/List/1/ABC`. My other routes work just fine.

I really have no idea what the problem is with my route. Do I need to change the order of my routes, or of the parameters in the URL?

Answer (score 1):

Routes should be listed in order from most specific to least specific.

Your `Inventory` route is overriding your `ListRestaurantInventory` because every route that you pass with 4 segments (such as `/Inventory/List/1/ABC`) beginning with an `Inventory` segment will match it. This essentially makes your `ListRestaurantInventory` route an unreachable execution path. Reversing the order of these 2 routes will fix this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ListRestaurantInventory",
    "Inventory/List/{restaurantLocationId}/{code}",
    new { controller = "Inventory", action = "ListRestaurantInventoryItems" },
    new[] { "MySite.Web.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Inventory",                            
    "Inventory/{restaurantName}/{restaurantLocationId}/{code}",
    new { controller = "Inventory", action = "Index" },
    new[] { "MySite.Web.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "InventoryDetails",
    "Inventory/{restaurantName}/{restaurantLocationId}/{code}/Details/{restaurantInventoryItemId}",
    new { controller = "Inventory", action = "Details" },
    new[] { "MySite.Web.Controllers" }
);
```